# Powershell script for uninstall Software

Tags: powershell

I need help with powershell script I need create script for deployment for many workstations which I push to the machines via deployment tool. I need uninstall app AzInfoProtection.exe the problem is that the path for this SW is different for each computer. So I don´t know I need find path by the executable file and after this create the command to uninstall it.

- app name: AzInfoProtection.exe
- Path somewhere: C:\ProgramData\Package
  Cache**\

I found this but I don´t know how can I get from the output the path

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache" -Filter AzInfoProtection.exe -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
```

So I need script that will uninstall this SW on many computer and the command for uninstalltion should be:

"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{ca644579-3d97-4c24-8bf0-a4ccd297b6a6}\AzInfoProtection.exe" /uninstall /quiet

this part is fro each computer different **{ca644579-3d97-4c24-8bf0-a4ccd297b6a6}** so I need script which find it.

I will be glad if you help me,
thanks

Comment: `$path = (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache" -Filter AzInfoProtection.exe -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force).Fullname`. Note that `$path` will be an array, if there are more than one instance of `AzInfoProtection.exe`.

Comment: if its installed, use the registry uninstall string. It will get you the location along with the arguments needed uninstall

Comment: @zett42 I create this: `$parameters = " \uninstall \quiet" $path = (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache" -Filter AzInfoProtection.exe -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force).Fullname $path + $parameters` output is `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{46465db4-81bc-48d7-adba-f6a3331fbce6}\AzInfoProtection.exe \uninstall \quiet` and I need `"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{46465db4-81bc-48d7-adba-f6a3331fbce6}\AzInfoProtection.exe" \uninstall \quiet` sorry but I am beginner at this. regarding the registry does not help me because there is the same problem as I described –

Comment: If it's an msi install:  `get-package *AzInfoProtection* | uninstall-package`

Comment: `$pathWithParams = "\`"$path\`" $parameters"` or slightly more readable: `$pathWithParams= '"{0}" {1}' -f $path, $parameters`. Also, you have the parameter slashes wrong, it should be `/uninstall /quiet`.